# How is there energy and charge in the universe?

Tags: cosmology, energy-conservation, charge, conservation-laws, big-bang

According law of conservation of charge "the total electric charge in the universe is constant and charge can neither be created nor be destroyed" so how did the existing charge came. I f it can not be created how it is was created in the first place

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community The question is fine. There is a bit of disconnect between the topics of the title (energy) and the question (charge).

Comment: Please clarify whether you are asking about *energy* or *charge* conservation. For energy conservation, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10309/50583. For charge conservation, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/133315/50583. If neither of these answers your question, please be more specific about what you want to know.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Your charge conservation answer is more mathematical than physical. We know directly of concrete phenomena that show the creation of charged particles from uncharged particles.

Comment: This might help. It talks about what energy is. [Basic energy question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/424479/37364)

Comment: For charges, here is a video by Don Lincoln of Fermilab - [Can leptogenesis explain why there's something instead of nothing?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsqEcGMjEfo&list=PLCfRa7MXBEsoJuAM8s6D8oKDPyBepBosS&index=9)

Answer (score 1):

Experimentally, we see processes like [pair production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production) that produce charged particles but conserve charge by producing equal positive and negative charge. We presume that the charged particles we see in the Universe were produced by such processes in the Big Bang.

Answer (score 1):

Well, indeed energy is not conserved in curved spacetime. It's only locally conserved.

Unless one takes into account the gravitional self energy.

[Gravitational Pseudo-Tensor of Energy-Momentum](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy%E2%80%93momentum_pseudotensor#:%7E:text=In%20the%20theory%20of%20general,gravitating%20matter%20to%20be%20defined.)

One possible cosmological scenario is that the total gravitational energy of the universe pluse the positive matter energy is zero.

[Zero Energy Universe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-energy_universe)

Energy can be considered as a Noether charge, and more generally the same applies to any charge in curved spacetime.

In supersymmetric theories there's a lower bound on the energy spectrum of the theory. That is an absolute zero for energy. Which perhaps not so accidentally, hints for the hidden link between supersymmetry and gravity in the format of Super Gravity theories.

Supersymmetry should definitely be spontaneously broken, either at tree level or more probably by None perturbative Quantum effects.

The problem would be, why the cosmological constant(energy density of the vacuum) is so small while the scale of SUSY breaking is very high.