# If $E = mc^2$, doesn't that mean we relatively have infinite energy?

Tags: special-relativity, mass-energy

I was going through the energy/mass equation and it is said that both of the said quantities are interconvertible. That made me think that if we try putting actual values into the equation, the interconversion is actually very large; speed of light itself is a large constant, and the product of its square and mass of a said object would be large. Putting our energy consumption into consideration then, why do we have energy problems in the world? Relative to our world's energy consumption, we should have infinite amount of energy for the world. Why is it that we still struggle with energy problems all over the world?

Comment: To reopen this post (v2) consider to only use the word _infinite_ in its mathematical meaning.

Comment: Hi Asad. Have a look at [What keeps mass from turning into energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/91501/what-keeps-mass-from-turning-into-energy) as that explains why we can't just turn matter into energy to get massive amounts of power.

Answer (score 2):

The energy that is trapped in rest mass energy is rather difficult to convert into other useful forms of energy, and so even if we have a lot of energy due to rest mass energy, they would not be that helpful to the energy budget crisis of the world.

And although $c^2$ is a huge constant, it is not infinite. Infinity is a lot bigger than any finite number.